# What is the use and point of unbound wildcards generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I don't understand what is the use of unbound wildcards generics. Bound wildcards generics with upper boundary `<? extends Animal>` makes perfect sense, because using polymorphism I can work with that type or collection. But what is the point of having generics that can be of any type? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of generics? Compiler doesn't find any conflict and after type erasure it would be like no generics was used.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An unbound type can be useful when your method doesn't really care about the actual type.

A primitive example would be this:

```
public void printStuff(Iterable<?> stuff) {
  for (Object item : stuff) {
    System.out.println(item);
  }
}
```

Since `PrintStream.println()` can handle all reference types (by calling `toString()`), we don't *care* what the actual content of that `Iterable` is.

And the *caller* can pass in a `List<Number>` or a `Set<String>` or a `Collection<? extends MySpecificObject<SomeType>>`.

Also note that not using generics (which is called using a raw type) at all has a quite different effect: it makes the compiler handle the *entire object* as if generics *don't exist at all*. In other words: not just the type parameter of the class is ignored, but also all generic type parameters on methods.

Another important distinctions is that you can't add any (non-`null`) value to a `Collection<?>`, but can add *all* objects to the raw type `Collection`:

This won't compile, because the type parameter of `c` is an unknown type (= the wildcard `?`), so we can't provide a value that is guaranteed to be assignable to that (except for `null`, which is assignable to all reference types).

```
Collection<?> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add("foo");    // compilation error
```

If you leave the type parameter out (i.e. use a raw type), then you can add *anything* to the collection:

```
Collection c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add("foo");
c.add(new Integer(300));
c.add(new Object());
```

Note that the compiler will *warn* you not to use a raw type, specifically for this reason: it removes any type checks related to generics.

Comment: But my question was : why to use generics then ? It can be "Iterable stuff" ... no sense in using wildcards

Comment: @Edgar: because a raw type (without generics) *only* exists for backwards compatibility: it effectively turns off all type checks for that type. While using a wildcard still does the type checks, but against an unkown type.

Comment: type check against an unknown type ? I don't get the last sentence in your answer "you can't add any (non-null) value to a Collection<?>, but can add all objects to the raw type Collection"

Comment: man I'm really trying to understand why it doesn't compile. There is a wildcard (any type / subtype of object) so it should be assigned a String right ? Why the compiler rejects to compile it ?

Comment: @Edgar: `?` doesn't just mean "I don't care". It means "some specific type, but I don't know which one". If you try to add `String` then the compiler asks "is `String` assignable to my type parameter"? If the type parameter is `Object` or `String`, then the answer is "yes". If the type parameter is "some specific type, but I don't know which one", then the answer is "I don't know!" which will be treated as if it were a "no".

Comment: I get it, it's hard to explain, but I see its purpose perfectly now. I've been using wildcards for a long time intuitively without even thinking about it much... thanks

Comment: Why do `public void printStuff(Iterable<?> stuff)` instead of `public <E> void printStuff(Iterable<E> stuff)`?

Comment: Just curious.  What's the difference between that and the following.  public static <T> void printStuff(Iterable<T> stuff) {
   for (Object item : stuff) {
     System.out.println(item);
   }
 }

Answer (score 8):

When you need to perform an `instanceof` check.

You can't parameterize like this:

```
Object value;
if (value instanceof List<String>) {
    // ...
}
```

So you do:

```
Object value;
if (value instanceof List<?>) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Effective Java 23 says `instanceof` checks are an acceptable use case for raw types, e.g. `value instanceof List` is okay.  Is there any advantage to using an unbounded wildcard versus a raw type?  Stated another way, why is `value instanceof List<?>` better than `value instanceof List`.

Comment: @JoeS [There's no difference at runtime actually.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959240/why-is-instanceof-operator-allowed-on-an-unbounded-wild-card-type-but-not-on-oth/14959326#comment57791198_14959326) I would recommend using the wildcard to make it clear that it is a "list of anything".

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to rephrase the question:

"What is the difference between `List<Object>` and `List<?>` ?"

The answer to that is that `List<?>` is more restrictive. It tells us that we have a bunch of object of **some** type, but that type is not necessarily `Object`.

Since we don't know what that type is, we cannot add to the list at all - anything we add may be of wrong type. In fact, we cannot pass any argument of `?` type to any method, not just `add()`.

On the plus side, when we specify that a method takes `List<?>`, it can take `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` or any other `List<>`. `List<Object>` can only take `List<Object>`.

Comment: So the answer is that List<?> is just a short version of List<? extends Object>, right?

Answer (score 2):

While using raw types means that you don't know about generics (because you're lazy or code was written ages ago), using `<?>` means that you know about generics and explicitly emphasize that your code can work with any kind of objects.

Answer (score 2):

There are (rare) perfectly correct use cases for unbound wildcards. The SDK contains some of them.

One example is a method that does a definite action on a list of any kind and does not return anything as `rotate` in `Collections`:

```
static void rotate(List<?> list, int distance)
```

Another example is when you want to list the possible constructors for a class, the method is :

```
Constructor<?>[] getConstructors()
```

Here it in not even possible to use a generic, because by definition the array will contain different constructor each with its own actual class. By contrast, the API does use a generic signature for getting one single constructor : `Constructor<T> getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)`.

The conclusion is that even if it is mainly used for compatibility with older code, there are still places where unbound wildcard generics are the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Using unbounded wildcards only makes sense, AFAIK, when wrapping old code that is not using generics, basically Collections.

If you look at what you can do with such a generic it's basically *nothing*. 
If you have a collection you can't add anything, if you try to read something out you will always get an `Object`and so on.

This in turns helps guaranteeing that you will handle the data in a type safe way, whereas using the raw type would have caused the compiler to ignore any mess you'd make.

[Which methods and fields are accessible/inaccessible through a reference variable of a wildcard parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Which%20methods%20and%20fields%20are%20accessible/inaccessible%20through%20a%20reference%20variable%20of%20a%20wildcard%20type?) from [Angelika Langers Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

List<Object> is a List that may contain any Object, e.g. l[0] may be an Integer, l[1] may be a String, etc.
List<?> may be a List<Integer> or List<String>, etc. If it is a List<Integer>, it stores only Integers, if it is List<String>, it stores only Strings.