# Difference between an unbound wildcard and a raw type

Tags: java, generics, unbounded-wildcard

I was reading about generics and I did not understand the need for unbound wildcards and how it differs from raw type. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671072/what-is-the-use-and-point-of-unbound-wildcards-generics-in-java) but still did not get it clearly. In the  [Java tutorial page for unbound wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) I got below two points and I did not understood first point:

> - If you are writing a method that can be implemented using functionality provided in the `Object` class.
> - When the code is using methods in the generic class that don't depend on the type parameter. For example, `List.size()` or `List.clear()`. In fact, `Class<?>` is so often used because most of the methods in `Class<T>` do not depend on `T`.

Can someone please explain the difference between unbound wildcard and raw type in layman language.

How does `List<?>` differ from `List<Object>`?

Comment: Note that the term "raw type" refers to an unparameterized reference to a generic type, e.g. `List` vs. `List<?>`. Slightly different concepts.

Comment: Just to point out that `List<Object>` is not a raw type, its generic type is `Object`.  A raw type would be `List`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> How `List<?>` differs from `List<Object>`

The main difference is that the first line compiles but the second does not:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

However, because you don't know what the generic type of `List<?>` is, you can't use its parameterized methods:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
list.add("aString"); //does not compile - we don't know it is a List<String>
list.clear(); //this is fine, does not depend on the generic parameter type
```

As for the difference with raw types (no generics), the code below compiles and runs fine:

```
List list = new ArrayList<String> ();
list.add("aString");
list.add(10);
```

Comment: got it so far but how raw type is different for unbound and why do we need unboud wildcard? can you please explain it with some good example.

Comment: @Sandy the main difference IMO is that use of unbound wildcard (e.g. in a method signature) signals a promise that the method in question is aware of generics and will honor the generic type of that object. With raw types all bets are off - you can add a number to a list of strings, as illustrated here - and mixing generic and raw code can lead to the risk of ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: @Sandy I illustrated the difference between unbouded (2nd example) and raw types (2rd example). What is not clear about them?

Comment: @assylias Nice answer. This comes a bit late, but I have this kind of structure, `List<ScheduledFuture<?>>`. In a wrapped executor, just to be able to better manage the tasks. So when I create a new scheduled task, it have to be returned. Otherwise the service cannot cancel the task. I cannot see any point in returning a generic `ScheduledFuture<?> newScheduledTask() {}` instead of just a raw, `ScheduledFuture newScheduledTask() {}`. What would you recommend in that case?

Comment: @patrik Using `<?>` forces the compiler to verify generics safety - if you use a raw type, the compiler won't check anything and it can create some insidious bugs (can't find an example right now though). Since it makes little difference, I would stick to using `<?>`.

Answer (score 6):

How `List<?>` differs from `List<Object>`?

```
    List<Object> l1 = new ArrayList();
    List<?> l2 = new ArrayList();
    l1.add("Object");
    //l2.add("Object");   incorrect
    l2.add(null);
```

You can only add null-value to the `List<?>`

Answer (score 6):

> Can someone please explain the difference between unbound wildcard and raw type in layman language.

Unbound wildcard type can maintain ***collection’s type invariant***, and raw type cannot. As Joshua Bloch says in his *Effective Java*,

> You can put any element into a collection with a raw type, easily corrupting the collection’s type invariant(as demonstrated by the unsafeAdd method on page 112); you can’t put any element (other than null) into a Collection<?>.

So, as long as you assign a list of parameterized type to a list of unbound wildcard type, ***collection’s type invariant*** will be maintained.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("foo");
list1.add("bar");
List<?> list2 = list1;
```

If you assign a list of raw type whose elements are of different types, unbound wildcard type will not maintain ***collection’s type invariant***, as the list is originally of type variant.

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add(1);
list1.add("foo");
List<?> list2 = list1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I found this [additional link from the Java tutorial on wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) helpful.

One of the main differences I see between `List<?>` and `List` is that the former can only ever be useful for reading from it's elements (unless you really want to add `null`), the latter allows (unchecked) adding of arbitrarily typed objects to it with possibly unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

List is useful in a method signature to call methods that never require the type parameter, i.e., read from the list or rotate it, for instance.

```
void someMethod(List<?> list) {
  list.clear();  // I will never add anything to the list in here
}
```

You will never add anything or otherwise modify the list with respect to the type it holds as you cannot add anything to the list except null in methods with this signature and thus you won't ever break type safety.
Raw List on the other hand you can do anything to, which as we all know can result in a type safety violation.

```
void someMethod2(List list) {
 list.add(new WeaselFurBrush());  
}
List list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
someMethod2(list1);// oops
```