# Difference between SomeClass and SomeClass<?>

Tags: java, generics, java-7

In Java 6 something like `MyClass` and `MyClass<?>` were considered equal but in Java 7 they are not.

With Java 7, as an example I stumble to problems with for example Hamcrest matchers that are given an instance of `MyClass` and a matcher that expects to match `MyClass<?>`, and they get compilation error saying

```
no suitable method found for assertThat(MyClass,Matcher<MyClass<?>>)
[ERROR] method Assert.<T#1>assertThat(T#1,Matcher<? super T#1>) is not applicable
[ERROR] (actual argument Matcher<MyClass<?>> cannot be converted to Matcher<? super MyClass> by method invocation conversion)
```

Why the change? What's the difference here between a rawtype and a generics type that has unspecified type argument?

Suggested answer does not really explain what I wonder here. One of the comments says "use of unbound wildcard (e.g. in a method signature) signals a promise that the method in question is aware of generics and will honor the generic type of that object." Here, again, I feel if it's just a "signal" it should not cause problems at compilation time.

I feel that `MyClass<?>` is just `MyClass` with information on what it contains or operates on, but while it's `<?>`, there's no added information and so they should be considered equal?

Comment: No, they weren't considered equal in Java 6 either. `MyClass` is a raw type, and `MyClass<?>` isn't. There's a big difference. Now I dare say the exact handling may have changed, but the claim that they were the same in Java 6 is incorrect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between an unbound wildcard and a raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242174/difference-between-an-unbound-wildcard-and-a-raw-type). See also: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: The code described above compiles with Java 6 and not with 7. But I'm mainly curious about the specifics of what you claim to be a big difference. I currently think there is no real difference except that it makes some code more cumbersome to write.

Comment: @PaulBellora The first one at least does not seem to answer my question.

Comment: @vertti They're very different. For instance, this compiles but fails at runtime: `List raw = new List(); raw.add("foo"); Integer i = (Integer) raw.get(0);` but this will fail at compile time when you try to add an item: `List<?> generic = new List<Object>(); generic.add("foo");`.

Comment: Your error message seems to indicate that the argument should be a `Matcher<? super MyClass>`, which is very different from a `Matcher<MyClass<?>>`. I don't see why Java 6 would allow it any more than Java 7. Perhaps the library itself changed?

Comment: @dlev it's the same test on the same maven build but run on either Oracle's Java 6 or 7.

Comment: @vertti  , its for type safety , explained it right , at runtime it will give exception so to prevent this , compile time method is evolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be related to a [compiler bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6638712) that was fixed in Java 7.

The compiler error that you now receive is correct. It looks like you're calling the method with wildcarded generic types, e.g. `MyClass<?>` and `Matcher<MyClass<?>>`. Note that a wildcard type argument means "some unknown type", so those arguments could really be `MyClass<String>` and `Matcher<MyClass<Integer>>`, which is obviously incorrect.

Using a raw type, e.g. plain `MyClass` *opts out* of generic type checking, which is why a call with raw types will compile (but likely fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException`).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

`MyClass` and `MyClass<?>` in Java 6 are not same ,

see this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

For backward compatibility, assigning a parameterized type to its raw type is allowed:

```
MyClass<String> stringBox = new MyClass<>();
MyClass rawBox = stringBox;               // OK
```

But if you assign a raw type to a parameterized type, you get a warning:

```
  MyClass rawBox = new MyClass();

  // rawBox is a raw type of MyClass<T>


  MyClass<Integer> intBox = rawBox;    

// warning: unchecked> conversion
```

`MyClass` is not a [Generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) Type , `MyClass<?>` is a generic type class which means , `MyClass` is a containing a type of another class ,

for eg , it is common in Java , we do like this

```
List<String> listofString = new ArrayList<String>();
```

here it means variable listofString is a object of List will restrict it contents to only String type of objects. `<String>` tells generic .

Comment: Formatting tip: Use backticks (\`) for inline code, especially if it contains generic types. Otherwise, the < and > will look like illegal HTML tags to SO, and it'll just strip them out. `List<String> foo` will look like just "List foo".

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said, they were not considered equal, that would be incorrect in my opinion. I cannot see any difference if I try in Java 6 and Java 7 - how do you tried this?

To understand the difference between a raw- and generics-type just have a look at this posting (scroll down to "How's a raw type different from using  as a type parameter?"):
[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I feel that the link you gave has an answer that kind of describes what I'm after here: "A raw type is define to be either:

    The name of a generic type declaration used without any accompanying actual type parameters."