# what is the logic of type erasure in java generics?

Tags: java, generics, types

As far as I know, type generics happens in the following code:

```java
public class Test {

    public void a(List<Object> list) {
    }

    public void a(List<String> list){
    }

    public void a(List<Integer> list){
    }

}
```

when the compiler compiles the code, the generic types will be erased so all the signatures are exactly same, which looks as follows:

```java
public class Test {

    public void a(List list) {
    }

    public void a(List list){
    }

    public void a(List list){
    }

}
```

If this is the logic, then:

```java
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
objList = strList;
```

is actually:

```
List objList = new ArrayList<>();
List strList = new ArrayList<>();
objList = strList;
```

which is OK because both of the two lists are same type.
However, In the above code, `objList = strList` will result an error.

Not quite sure what is the real logic. And what is more, the difference between `List<?>`, List(without any braces) and `List< Object>`

Comment: Because type erasure happens after compilation; the compiler prevents `objList = strList;`. Thus it is not a problem. Also that is basically the point of generic types. To prevent `objList = strList` at compile time. Type erasure is a side effect of the implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement [@Giorgi Tsiklauri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68694372/9304999),

For the class below:

```java
class Box<T> {
    T t;

    T getT() { return t; }

    void setT(T t) { this.t = t; }
}
```

because of type erasure, compiler compiles the class to:

```java
class Box {
    Object t;

    Object getT() { return t; }

    void setT(Object t) { this.t = t; }
}
```

So, when you instantiate the `Box<T>` generic class with type argument `Integer` as follows:

```java
Box<Integer> box = new Box<Integer>();
box.setT(10);
Integer t = box.getT();
```

the compiler knows that the `Box<T>` is instantiated with `Integer` because, at compile time, it sees that `Box<Integer>`. So, type casts are inserted by compiler. So the code above is compiled into:

```java
Box box = new Box();
box.setT(10);
Integer t = (Integer) box.getT(); // compiler inserts type casts in lieu of us!
```

No matter how you instantiate the generic, the compiler doesn't create additional class files. If what actually happens at type erasure is replacement(replaces `T` with type argument such as `Integer`), the compiler have to create additional classes for `Box` for `Integer`, `Box` for `Double` etc — But that's not what actually happens at type erasure:

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded. — [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety. — [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead. — [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generics are invariant: for any two distinct types `U` and `V`, `List<U>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `List<V>`. (Joshua Bloch, Effective Java)

You can't put any value except `null` into a `List<?>`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only site.

Comment: sorry. Edited to english version.

Answer (score 0):

The diff between List<?> and List is the former can take any type either an Object class or any other object. The latter can take only object

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String> // compile error

List<?> list = new ArrayList<String>  //no error
```

List<?extends Comparator> (boundedd) will get converted to List after compile
List Unbounded are converted to Object whereas for bounded the Java compiler replaces the bounded type parameter T with the first bound class.

For more details
[Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: so what is difference between  List<?> list= new ArrayList()  and  List list= new ArrayList()

Comment: List<?> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1.1); //Compile error
        List list1  = new ArrayList();
        list1.add(1.1); /No error
       In this example, the compiler processes the as being of type Object. When we call add method invokes the compiler is not able to confirm the type of object that is being inserted into the list, and an error is produced.

Answer (score -1):

> If this is the logic, then..

No, that is not what happens.

Type erasure is a process that takes place during compilation, and for specific object allocations (objects, created using `new`), compiler *erases* all the generic type parameters (e.g. `Box<T>`) with corresponding generic type arguments (e.g. `Box<Integer>`).

This means, that if you have defined your class:

```java
class Box<T> {
}
```

and then invoked that type (instantiated), as:

```java
Box<Integer> intBox = new Box<>();
```

in the compiled version, instantiation of `intBox` will allocate the object, on the heap, having swapped all the appearances of `T` with `Integer`.

Therefore, in your example:

```java
public class Test {

    public void a(List<Object> list) {
    }

    public void a(List<String> list){
    }

    public void a(List<Integer> list){
    }

}
```

you are *invoking* a parametrized type (generic) and you declare method's local parameter with generic type *argument*.

For the object referenced by the variable of type `List<String>`, compiler have erased all the appearances of `List`'s `E` with `String`, and for `List<Integer>` - `E` will be replaced by `Integer`.

For the final part of your confusion, I'd suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242174/difference-between-an-unbound-wildcard-and-a-raw-type).

Comment: Wrong: For the `Box`, the `T` is replaced by `Object`, **not `Integer`**. If you use the generic type `Box` as `Box<Integer>`, you just get `Box`. But, to provide type safety, the compiler inserts type casts. For example, `Integer value = box.getValue();` is converted to `Integer value = (Integer)box.getValue();`(Yes, the getter returns `Object`, not `Integer`), assuming that there are member `T value;` and its getter. For the information, read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

Comment: @rosshjb did you read the text carefully? I don't think so, but you've rushed into downvote. e.g. means "for example", and not always. "compiler erases all the generic type parameters (e.g. Box<T>) with corresponding generic type arguments (e.g. Box<Integer>)" - is what I say. Moreover, after that I give an example of `Box<Integer>` which is indeed a case of type erasure with Integer. So, what's wrong?

Comment: You are saying that type params are replaced by type args, on and on. See the statements you wrote `"E will be replaced by Integer."` or `"having swapped all the appearances of T with Integer"` — That's not actually happened in type erasure. For `class Box<T> {}` and `Box<Integer> box;`, the compiler erases type parameters and type arguments, and they are compiled to `class Box {}` and `Box box`(raw type) respectively. At the use site, the compiler knows that the `box` is instantiated with type argument `Integer` so type cast would be inserted like `Integer value = (Integer)box.getValue();`.

Comment: After type erasure, type parameters and type arguments all are gone. Actually, "replacement" also doesn't happen too. Type erasure erases, not replaces, the things. After type erasure, just `Object`(for raw type) is left to support backward compatibility.

Comment: I wrote an answer with more specific example. If my downvote to your answer hurts you, you can downvote [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70506699/9304999) too. I just wanted to correct your answer.