# Why is instanceof operator allowed on an unbounded wild card type but not on other parameterized types in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I think due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) , using `instanceof` and `class literals` are not allowed for `parameterized generic types` except `unbounded wild card types` . Why did the Java language designers allowed this exception ? There isn't any role of type erasure for unbounded wild card types ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point is that an object knows its concrete class - but not the generic type arguments for that. So if we construct an `ArrayList<Integer>`, that knows at execution time that it's an `ArrayList` of *some* kind - but it doesn't know about the `Integer` part.

The "`ArrayList` of some kind" part is precisely what `ArrayList<?>` means, which is why:

```
if (foo instanceof ArrayList<?>)
```

is valid. It's just equivalent to using the raw type:

```
if (foo instanceof ArrayList)
```

Comment: but isn't there meta data for the compiler to say that the `field foo` is of type `ArrayList<Integer>` at run time ? I am referring to [your answer only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/339708/1527084)

Comment: @Geek: Yes, but that's for a *field*, not an *object*. They're different.

Comment: Why is checking against `ArrayList<?>` the same as using the raw type `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Francesco: How would you expect them to be different?

Comment: The former uses a wildcard and is a "list of anything" while the latter omits the type parameter and is just a "list". How are they the same thing?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani: They're the same thing at execution time due to type erasure - see the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: So when would you use one or another? Why is using the wildcard allowed if it yields the same result as the raw type?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani: I'm honestly not sure why it's allowed, to be honest. Maybe it's so that you can make it clear that it *is* a generic type you're testing against?