# Using unknown generic type with List class

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

Given a *concrete* class:

```
public class Book {
    // ... 
}
```

And a `java.util.List` initialization:

```
List<?> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

The following line of code does *not* compile:

```
myList.add(new Book());
```

So what is the purpose of using the *unknown* generic type in a `List` if you aren't able to add anything to the list?

You may be able to do `.get()` and other read operations on the object, but why would you do so before it's even initialized?

Comment: As the question is now closed as a duplicate, I added an answer to [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671072/what-is-the-use-and-point-of-unbound-wildcards-generics-in-java)

Comment: I'm unsure whether it is a true duplicate. But many answers to the other question are relevant for yours (mine should be :-) ). Feel free to edit your question and to ping me in comment if you need some precisions.

Comment: You would never write `List<?> myList = new ArrayList<Book>();` in real code. `List<?>` only makes sense as a parameter of return type of a method like the examples I gave in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31749894/3545273).

Answer (score 0):

**You don't** use the unknown generic type in a `List` when *initializing*.
**You do** use it when: see the duplicate link.